# How to use DistributedMapCacheClient service as a Property in nifi custom Processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to use DistributedMapCacheClient service as a Property in my nifi custom Processor. Everything was fine but when I am going to configure the the Processor in Nifi, I am getting the following error message.

"No controller service types found that are applicable for this property."

This is how I have configured the Property in my code.

```
public static final PropertyDescriptor DISTRIBUTED_CACHE_SERVICE = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
            .name("Distributed Cache Service")
            .description("")
            .required(false)
            .identifiesControllerService(DistributedMapCacheClient.class)
            .build();
```

Please let me know how can I use DistributedMapCacheClient service as a Property in my processor.

Answer (score 3):

I was missing below dependencies in my pom file. After I added those, my custom processor was working fine. I Found the answer in this [link](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/77570/maven-nar-plugin-looks-to-not-bundle-all-the-depen.html).

1. Added the scope as provided for the dependency, nifi-distributed-cache-client-service-api.
2. Added the dependency for nifi-standard-services-api-nar (type = nar)